# Tomcat multiroom chat

Tags: java, sockets, tomcat, websocket, chat

I'm trying to make a multi-room chat application using Tomcat Server (7) and web sockets. I currently have my project configured such that users can access a web page, enter their names, and join one chat room (and talk with each other).

I'm wondering, conceptually (maybe even pseudo-code), how I would implement this to handle multiple chat rooms. I started trying to implement this by creating and ArrayList of Room class objects (each one has an ID and an ArrayList of sessions), and then I was hypothesizing to only send data to users whose session IDs mach the same room object as the person who sent it, but I realized there must be an easier, less process-intensive (and simpler) way to do this.

I've heard rumors about multi-threading, but I have no idea where to start with that (or how to implement it here).

Any ideas?

Comment: What do you see as process intensive about your approach?

Comment: @Warren See well I guess it's not too process intensive, I was just wondering what alternatives there are